# Recover encrypted home directory files

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs

I tried to recover the home directory files using:

```
sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private /media/USERNAME/home/
```

Now everything is mounted properly and I can see the files using `ls`
but can't copy or open files.

Output of `ls -l` of directory and files are

```
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Directory name
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my secure-mount.py wrapper script (see here: http://memobadz.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/encrypting-directories-using-ecryptfs/ )

```
secure-mount.py --import /home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME
secure-mount.py --mount  /home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME
```

=> put in the password you were using on that machine.

(No need for root)

You should be able to see your files in /home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME

Good luck.